# Change Accent Color in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp

I dont really want to use the accent color that the user has chosen in Windows in my app, and instead want to have my own color show.
I can change it manually on all the items by by making new styles, but it is just in so many places in the normal controls, that it would be nice to do on the app level.

I tried setting `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemAccentColor" Color="#FFCB2128" />` but for some reason that does noting on some items and turns others like the video controls gray.

Comment: U need to set target types on ur style to automatically apply to types set in target types.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti That answer only applies to Windows Phone (8/8.1) and not windows 10 UWP. So it has not really been answered.

Comment: Sorry, **if it doesn't work** then let me know and I'll retract close vote (actually vote to reopen...)

Comment: Thanks Brandon, but that is what I want to avoid, so i dont have to do it on all the controls I use, and instead overwrite the accentcolor in app.xaml or app.xaml.cs.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Unfortuneatly it does not work in UWP, I have already tried. :-(

Comment: It does work u just set the target type in the style tag and set the property setters inside.

Comment: @BrandonSeydel If I understand you right I would still have to set a custom style for each control.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On Win10 UWP, System Accent color is defined as ThemeResource `SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush`.
You can override it as following.

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="Orange" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="Green" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="Blue" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Comment: I have changed it the way you did here and it works, but my ExtendedSplashScreen still have its Accent Color as White... Any idea why?

Comment: Where do you put this code?  the mainfest?  app.xaml?  The page xaml??

Comment: 'SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush'! That's what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @vcapra1 Shove it in app.xaml.

Answer (score 25):

To change accent color on every system control you have to redefine the system resource as follows.

Note that `SystemAccentColor` **is a color, not a brush**. If you don't redefine all other brushes, the color won't be applied on everything.

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
  <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">     
    <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FF20A060</Color>  <!--Your accent color-->

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlDisabledAccentBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltAccentBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentHighBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.9" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentLowBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.6" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAltListAccentMediumBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.8" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentHighBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.9" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.6" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightListAccentMediumBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Opacity="0.8" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHyperlinkTextBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogBorderThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="JumpListDefaultEnabledBackground" Color="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" />
  </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

Comment: it actually is enough to just supply `SystemAccentColor`, the rest will be applied accordingly... Maybe just since the last update (?)

Comment: I'm not sure what last update you mean, but I have the latest Windows build and VS2015 Update 1 RC with updated version of UWP kit installed and if I define only SystemAccentColor, some controls use it, but some still keep displaying original color.

Comment: Hi again! I just literally double checked. In my project all of those colors you listed change when setting `SystemAccentColor` and nothing more is needed.

Comment: I would be really interested in your code, in fact the whole project, to test it on my machine. Would it be possible to share it somewhere for me to download? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't do that. But I just added `<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#00FF00</Color>` to https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics in Application -  Application.Resources - ResourceDictionary and everything went greeen as described.
Maybe you just set the color for one theme and it gets overridden some place else? or it really is depending on some version.

Comment: Sure, no problem, I just thought you have a testing project. Anyway, I have found the problem. The difference in my application is in that, that I redefine template for some controls. I don't manipulate the brushes, I just alter original template that applies for all controls of the type. In this case I have to refine all brushes. If I don't define new templates only "SystemAccentColor" is enough - just like you said. Thanks for helping me figure out the issue!

Comment: That is good to know! But it brings up the question...Did you use StaticResource or ThemedResource in your controls? And if you were using staticResources, did you fix it by switching?

Comment: They were just a copy of the original controls with minimal changes. No changes to their resources at all, so they all are using ThemeResource. Since I started with UWP I'm encountering such oddities all the time. It's a mess.

Comment: How do you override a Theme Resource using code? I'm trying, but no dice at all!

Comment: At least one color seems to be missing when targeting SDK 17134. In combo boxes the background color of the selected item seems to have been changed.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following to App.xaml if you are not using any templates or ResourceDictionaries:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

If you are using the Minimal Template10 template, then add the following line to Styles/Custom.xaml after the CustomColor and ContrastColor values:

```
<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
```

If you have your own ResourceDictionary somewhere else, linked from App.xaml, then similarly add the "Color" line there.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was setting

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemAccentColor" Color="#FFCB2128" />
    <Color x:Key="SystemAltHighColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAltLowColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAltMediumColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAltMediumHighColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemAltMediumLowColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemBaseHighColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemBaseLowColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemBaseMediumColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemBaseMediumHighColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
    <Color x:Key="SystemBaseMediumLowColor">#FFCB2128</Color>
```

In the app.xaml file in order to overwrite the onese set by windows.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever wants to do it in C#, here's how:

In App.cs, in the OnLaunched method, write this:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    //Use Argb values
    Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"] = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100, 100);

    //Use predefined colors
    Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"] = Colors.Black;

    //Rest of the code
    ...
}
```