# Change the window border colour in my UWP App in WinJS

Tags: visual-studio, win-universal-app, winjs, windows

How do I change the window border colour of my app ?

For example, in Microsoft's One Note 2013 app, the purple colour is also on the bar at the top as well as over the minimize, maximize and close buttons.

I am using visual studio 2015.

I have looked in the app manifest and can't seem to find anything

Comment: See the new OneNote app for example (for windows 10 in my case). When you open it it's normal and once it's loaded it changes purple. I'm almost certain you can do it, just not sure how :/ @CodyGray

Comment: @CodyGray answer below solved my question perfectly, thought you may be interested :)

Comment: I thought by me saying 'windows app' and 'the window border colour of my app' was enough. Sure it was enough for @nuitech. I'll update my question to make it more obvious for future readers

Comment: Point taken, my fault. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @CodyGray have you noticed WinJS in the title? This stands for UWP.

Comment: Clearly I'm out of my depth here. As I stated in the first comment, I don't know what WinJS is. I'll go back to writing desktop apps, thankyouverymuch. Where title bars get the color *I* want them to have. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the app title bar color using the [ApplicationViewTitleBar class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewtitlebar.aspx):

```js
var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView();
appView.titleBar.backgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.black; // or {a: 255, r: 0, g: 0, b: 0}
appView.titleBar.inactiveBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.black;
appView.titleBar.buttonBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.black;
appView.titleBar.buttonHoverBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.black;
appView.titleBar.buttonPressedBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.black;
appView.titleBar.buttonInactiveBackgroundColor = Windows.UI.Colors.black;
```

Comment: Thanks, that kinda works, but doesnt change the whole 'titlebar'. Changes up to the minimize, and then the minimize, maximize and close bakgrounds are still white ? Any ideas ? Also, you know how I pass my own colour ? Say : 'rgba(70, 130, 180, 1);' or '#4682B4' for example rather than from the windows colors class

Comment: @thisOneGuy For the title bar buttons background, use appropriate attributes of the ApplicationViewTitleBar class. For custom color, you can use the Color object: `{a: Number, r: Number, g: Number, b: Number}`

Comment: Brilliant. Works exactly how I wanted. Thank you very much :)

Comment: what about the border? it is still taking the color set in my pc settings!!

Comment: @LayaleMatta Have you tried setting `<Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FF000000</Color>` inside `<ResourceDictionary>` in your app.xaml file?

Comment: When I add  `<Application.Resources><ResourceDictionary><Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FF000000</Color></ResourceDictionary></Application.Resources> ` it gives an error: The property "Resources" can only be set once.

Comment: @LayaleMatta `<ResourceDictionary>` should be inside `<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33854662/912946).

Comment: Didn't work. Even OneNote UWP App has a border with the color set in my Windows settings. This should be by default right? Cause the solution you gave me didn't work. Any idea?