# Xamarin.Forms: Set border color of TextBox in UWP

Tags: xamarin, textbox, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to change the border color of a `TextBox` to use it in Xamarin.Forms. This is done via a custom renderer.

**First try:**

Custom renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    var control = this.Control as TextBox;
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(0, 8, 38, 85));
    }
}
```

Result: the border color is gone and it changes to my color after I click into the `TextBox`

**Second try:**

Custom renderer (subclass from `EntryRenderer`):

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    if(this.Control == null)
    {
        var control = new ColoredTextBox();
        SetNativeControl(control);
    }

    base.OnElementChanged(e);
}
```

Custom control:

```
public class ColoredTextBox : FormsTextBox
{
    protected override void OnGotFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);

        var control = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        control.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(0, 88, 128, 85));
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);

        var control = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        control.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(0, 88, 128, 85));
    }
}
```

Result: app crashes with

> **Exception**: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   **StackTrace (last line)**: at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.SetNativeControl(TNativeElement control)

**Third try:**

Custom renderer changed to `ViewRenderer`:

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomEntry, ColoredTextBox>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomEntry> e)
    {
        var view = Element as CustomEntry;

        if (e.OldElement != null || view == null)
            return;

        var textBox = new ColoredTextBox();
        SetNativeControl(textBox);

        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Result: the border color is gone and it changes to my color after I click into the `TextBox`. Furthermore the text I set in XAML is not set on the new control (but thats no surprise). Now the `OnGotFocus()` and `OnLostFocus()` events are called, but as written before they do not bring the desired effect. Interestingly, the events are called all the time if I set a breakpoint and it doesn't stop calling.

How can I programmatically change the border color of a `TextBox` in UWP?

**Edit:**

Regarding the duplicate: The linked question targets the accent color in general, but refers to the `TextBox` as example. Mainly my goal was to do it programmatically and NOT by style/theme. Since there currently seems no other way to do it, the solution is nearly the same. So I'll leave it up to the community do decide if it is a duplicate or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the accent colour of a Xamarin.Forms UWP application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050302/how-do-i-change-the-accent-colour-of-a-xamarin-forms-uwp-application)

Comment: I wanted to change the color in code, so that I later could implement a property. So I shouldn't use a custom renderer at all? Should I setup a style with `TargetType='TextBox'` in the App.xaml of the UWP project? How should this work together? Can you improve your selected answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `UWP project` in `App.Xaml` add the following code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush" Color="#YourHexColourHere" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

this overrides the style set by `Xamarin.Forms` which is shown [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FormsTextBoxStyle.xaml)

Comment: Yep, that is what I also found out. I have to set `SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush`, `SystemControlForegroundChromeDisabledLowBrush` and `SystemControlHighlightChromeAltLowBrush` to change a simple border color. How would one make the changes in code?

Comment: If I get this right you have to make the changes for `Light`, `Dark`, and `Default` theme?

Comment: The idea to do this in code is to control the color from the XF project (e.g. via custom property). Currently you have to specify the colors in each project. Is there any possibility to do this in code or is your solution the only one?

Comment: @testing I think this is the only way. on UWP it concerns [this line](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UAP/FormsTextBoxStyle.xaml#L138)

Comment: I have to try it, but I think [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33812715/426227) should also work in the custom renderer. So you could set this line in code. I also noticed that there are some side effects if you set the styles like above. On one place you change it, but you change it on another place too, where you don't want to have this ... Do you know in which order the styles are applied (e.g. if you think on [the approach from Vishnu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38117908/426227)? First the XF style and then the UWP style?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control != null)
        {
            if(Resources.ThemeDictionaries.ContainsKey("SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush"))
            {
                var borderBrush = Resources.ThemeDictionaries["SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
                borderBrush.Color = ###desired color!
            };

        }
    }
```