# Apply style to control in custom renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to apply a style to a control. This is the style

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundColor" Color="Yellow" />

        <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="myNewButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

, which can be found in *App.xaml* (UWP project). And here is the custom renderer:

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (this.Element != null)
    {
        var style = Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.Resources["myNewButtonStyle"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.Style;
        this.Control.Style = style;
    }
}
```

The idea is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38117908/426227). But the style isn't applied. Setting the background color in code does work:

```cs
this.Control.BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow);
```

How can I apply a style to a control in a custom renderer?

Comment: <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Backgroundcolor" Color="Yellow" />                       <Style TargetType="Button" x:Name="myNewButtonStyle">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Backgroundcolor}" />
        </Style>

Comment: Setter Property may be "BackgroundColor" not Background only. Try it

Comment: *Unknown member 'BackgroundColor' on element 'Button'*. *The member "BackgroundColor" is not recognized or is not accessible.*

Comment: Which class does your custom renderer derive from? Is the renderer built for a normal Button control?

Comment: @MZetko: The control is a subclass form `Xamarin.Forms.Button` and the renderer is a subclass from `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.ButtonRenderer`. In this example it should be a normal button control, but I want to style different controls. Button is only on of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've filled a bug report. It should be fixed in one of the upcoming releases (> XF 2.3.3.166-pre4).