# Change UWP window border color?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Can't seem to find the way to change the thin border color for a Windows UWP app. Many places point to this discussion: [Change Accent Color in Windows 10 UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831917/change-accent-color-in-windows-10-uwp). And I've used that information and other articles to change the SystemAccentColor, which changes some things about the running app. But after trying many different other magic theme keys to affect the window border I'm not sure what to do. Here's a picture of what I'm talking about - notice the magenta border along the edge.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, this color is determined by the system accent color in the Settings app. You can only change the title bar color for your app.

(Have you seen any store app which was able to change this color?)

Comment: Good to know, and that settles that. Do you know of any doc that states this btw?

Comment: No, unfortunately. This is anecdotal, but I'm 99% sure you can't. It's easy to find documentation that confirms things are possible, but not the other way around. We need someone from Microsoft to confirm this.